# Сортировка таблицы по частям

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица ACCOUNT_SCENARIO:

[image: ACCOUNT_SCENARIO]

В которой есть колонка ACCOUNT_TYPE, которая отражает иерархию, которых всего 3 - 'CE', 'CF', 'SP'.

Возможно ли отсортировать таблицу сначала для первой иерархии, затем для второй и в конце для 3-й? При этом, каждая последующая сортировка не должна задевать предыдущую.

А вот собственно и сам алгоритм сортировки (сортируем по колонке из другой таблицы под название ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY):

```
SELECT ACSC.* 
FROM ACCOUNT_SCENARIO AS ACSC
JOIN (SELECT PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID, MIN(EXCEL_ORDER) AS EXCEL_ORDER
FROM ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY  
WHERE ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY_ID = 'SP'
GROUP BY PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
) X ON ACSC.ACCOUNT_ID = X.PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'SP'
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_TYPE, X.EXCEL_ORDER, ACCOUNT_DATE
```

Comment: Конечно возможно, во внутрь order by пишите ф-цию сортировки, с сравнениями с конструкцией `case when then else end` с умножениями делениями ветвлениями сортируете в любой последовательности.

Comment: Забыл довавить - с подзапросами. (например `order by (select a from table1 where table1.id = x.id) `

Comment: @nick_n_a извините за наглость, но не можете ли вы сбросить пример такой сортировки? В гугл умею, только боюсь найти не то, что нужно.

Comment: По вопросу не совсем понятно что именно вам нужно, но для "трех случаев", я бы записал так `order by coalesce(case when  ACCOUNT_TYPE='CE' then  expression_1 end,  case when  ACCOUNT_TYPE='CF' then expression_2 end,   case when  ACCOUNT_TYPE='SP' then expression_3 end )`  подзапросы я показал. Дальше - пробуйте - получится.

Comment: @nick_n_a Никак не могу понять, что я делаю не так:

https://pastebin.com/yGDfDkGe

Comment: У вас таблицы внутри order by не связаны с внешними. Я допустим, делал так  `select * from filials order by   (select name from regions where regions.id = filials.region_id )` а у вас отсутствует связь с главной выборкой. это вообще достаточно запутано, могу предложить сделать выбоку с *полями по которым идёт сортировка*, а потом обвернуть эту выборку сортировкой. Так будет гораздо проще и скорость можно будет увеличить маневрируя join-ами. Приведите таблицу к виду `select fields, order1, order2, order3,   ACCOUNT_TYPE from ( ... )  t`  тогда вам останется дописать условие в `order by` и всё